# Hide element in nodeJs, with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I'm new to nodeJs and been playing around with it. I've also tried NodeJs express and it all seems fine. However I've been trying to use Jquery in such a manner that it can handle client side operations, like effects and the like but seem to fail with even the most basic things. So the code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../public/javascripts/indexSite.js"></script>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css'/>
</head>
<body>
<h1><%= title %></h1>

<p>Welcome to <%= title %></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Which is just the index.ejs file that is created when creating a project in nodeJs express with the addition of two script tags. The indexSite.Js file is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").hide();
});
```

Which is rather simple yet I fail to actually hide the body.. Also when checking the console the application,server what have you, pick up the indexsite.js file:

```
GET /public/javascripts/indexSite.js 404 5.113 ms - 856
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 6.886 ms - -
GET / 304 1.753 ms - -
```

So I'm rather dumbfounded

Comment: Did you see that `404` at `GET /public/javascripts/indexSite.js 404 5.113 ms - 856`?

Comment: Clearly I did not, totally missed that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a 404 (Not found error) on indexSite.js.

Replace :

```
<script src="../public/javascripts/indexSite.js"></script>
```

With :

```
<script src="/javascripts/indexSite.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why is everything so simple.. yet I seem to miss it constantly. Thank you nevertheless

Comment: You're welcome, don't hesitate to push the arrow up next the answer ;-)